# Suggestion about drag and amplify pulse

Tags: photodiode, preamp

Following picture is Photodiode I/V pre-amp of my circuit

[image]

My target pulse from OPA356 output, which range is `15mVpp /130ns-width` to `150mVpp /1us-width`.

**I'd like to add drag/amplify circuit after Vo.**

Drag/amplify circuit would be:

- Set V/V gain: 20X
- Drag timescale: 1000x

So the output range would be `150mVpp /130us-width` to `1.5Vpp /1ms-width` after drag/amplify.

For instance:

[image]

Any good ideas for this circuit?

Comment: What do you expect for output of the stretcher circuit whose input amplitude is below 15mV? A different idea: It might be simpler to output a constant-amplitude pulse whose time-span is proportional to the integrated input pulse (amplitude * time).

Comment: Thanks @glen_geek 's reply. I've googled. Do you mean "pulse shaping"? I glanced this [link](https://ns.ph.liv.ac.uk/~ajb/ukgs_nis/pre-course-material/lec2-03.pdf). It seems to use integrator as the first stage for drag pulse but amplitude would be reduced, so add differentiator to enhance amplitude. <- Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Much effort in that document tries to mitigate pulse pile-up - a problem when you stretch time (as you intend too). You haven't mentioned if input pulse separation can be closer than 130us. It is a good document, showing how nuclear pulses are processed, where pulses can occur in quick succession - a problem exacerbated when pulses/sec increases.

Answer (score 0):

The input goes through a buffer amplifier that drives a comparator and a 20x amplifier.

The comparator extracts both the leading and trailing edges of the input pulse, and enables/disables two current sources.

The comparator output leading edge starts a short timer.  The output of the timer clocks a sample-and-hold (S/H) circuit.  This delays clocking the S/H until input transients, overshoots, ringing, etc. have dies out.

The output of the 20x amplifier goes to the input of the S/H.  This captures the desired output voltage so it is stable after the input pulse has ended.  The output of the S/H is the system output pulse.

The input comparator also controls two current sources.  The first is enabled when the input pulse is high, charging a timing ramp capacitor at some fixed rate.  The second is enabled when the input is low, discharging the timing cap at 1/1000 the charge rate.  A comparator on this cap voltage resets the S/H cap when the timing cap is discharged, terminating the system output pulse.

As long as the input voltage is below the input comparator threshold, both the S/H cap and the ramp cap are held low in their reset states.

OSLT

Or Something Like That.

Comment: Thanks your reply. Could you show a brief example circuit?